# Freeform and ISO 8601 duration parser

Tags: library, haskell

Is there a Haskell library that can parse durations similar to these examples?

```
5 hours
5h 30m
1 d 5 h 30 m
PT12H30M5S
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an small ISO duration parser:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Text.Parsec as P
import Control.Lens

pInt = P.many P.digit <&> (\x -> read x :: Int)
pX letter multiplier = P.option 0  $ (pInt <&> (*) multiplier) <* P.char letter
pYear = pX 'Y' 31557600
pMon = pX 'M' 2629800
pDay = pX 'D' 86400
pHour = pX 'H' 3600
pMin = pX 'M' 60
pSec = pX 'S' 1

pTime = P.option 0 $ P.char 'T' *> sequence [pHour, pMin, pSec] <&> sum
pFull = P.char 'P' *> sequence [pYear, pMon, pDay, pTime] <&> sum

parseDuration = P.parse pFull "(source)"
parseDuration "PT1H"
```